Flutter White screen of death. App loads fine in debug mode cant load in release mode(apk)
I have tried flutter clean, running FlutterError in the main method, running app in release mode, inserting internet permission in manifest file, changing compile and target sdks in the build.gradle file but no error is thrown and most of debug techniques but nothing works. Any help is welcome.
Below is my Splash Screen that loads initially
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:flyber/core/app_export.dart';
import 'package:flyber/presentation/onboarding_screen_seven_screen/onboarding_screen_seven_screen.dart';
import 'package:flyber/widgets/spacing.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class SplashScreensThreeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<SplashScreensThreeScreen> createState() =>
      _SplashScreensThreeScreenState();
}

class _SplashScreensThreeScreenState extends State<SplashScreensThreeScreen> {
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    Timer(Duration(seconds: 3), () {
      Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(
          MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => OnboardingScreenSevenScreen()));
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      top: false,
      child: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: ColorConstant.primary,
        body: Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
          children: [
            VerticalSpace(height: 40),
            Align(
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              child: Text(
                Constants.appName,
                overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: ColorConstant.whiteA700,
                  fontSize: getFontSize(
                    28,
                  ),
                  fontFamily: 'Fira Sans',
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                  letterSpacing: 1.12,
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Container(
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              margin: getMargin(
                bottom: 30,
              ),
              child: RichText(
                text: TextSpan(
                  children: [
                    TextSpan(
                      text: "Powered by",
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: ColorConstant.whiteA700,
                        fontSize: getFontSize(
                          16,
                        ),
                        fontFamily: 'Fira Sans',
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                        letterSpacing: 0.64,
                      ),
                    ),
                    TextSpan(
                      text: " Flyber",
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: ColorConstant.whiteA700,
                        fontSize: getFontSize(
                          16,
                        ),
                        fontFamily: 'Fira Sans',
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                        letterSpacing: 0.64,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}


I suggest you tried   dhiwise post on Troubleshooting
especially Analyzing and Fixing persistent error:
Look for any exceptions or warnings indicating where the error occurs.
consider adding more detailed error handling throughout your code, for more clarity.
FlutterError.onError = (FlutterErrorDetails details) {

Sometimes, the white screen error might be related to specific widgets not being built as expected. To investigate, you can use debugPrint.
debugPrint('MyApp build method called');

Have you inspect others widget, if any that might have usage on this screen?

I tried this through the same link no error was logged

Well thats harsh, maybe you could go to a real Flutter Expert or remake the project altogether ( this usually works)

Ensure you have the internet permission set in the AndroidManifest.xml file for both debug and release configurations.
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>


Tried this before

After thorough research, the issue was originating from this method of getting dynamic screen dimensions
 Size size = WidgetsBinding.instance.window.physicalSize /
WidgetsBinding.instance.window.devicePixelRatio;;

It was fine in debug but in release it was returning zero always. Thus hiding every widget
